# Why allowing lossy operations at first place when it is unnecessary?

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

Apology for my non technical terminology. Consider solving $x+\sqrt{x}=0$ for real solutions. It leads to an extra solution $x=1$ at the step squaring both sides of $$x=-\sqrt{x}$$

And that's where information loss is happening which leads to an extra false positive root. But using $i^2=-1$ the squaring process would not be lossy anymore (both sides agree on sign and squaring would not dismiss information) and there would not be an extra solution: $$x(x-i)=0$$ Why this is not the default behavior instead of checking the solutions later as an extra step?

Comment: Because $(a)^2=(-a)^2$. Consider $x-2=0$; there is only one solution: $x=2$. If you "square" it, you get $x^2=4$ and now the root $-2$ will creep in...

Comment: You didn't explain how you went from $x=-\sqrt{x}$ to $x(x-i)=0$. You also claim that there would be no extra solution now, but $x=i$ is a solution to $x(x-i)=0$ while it is *not* a solution to $x=-\sqrt{x}$, since $-\sqrt{i}=-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\neq i$.

Comment: maybe using $i$ was a bad idea at first place. I was looking for what @henry did to avoid information loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ x = -\sqrt{x} \implies x^2=x \implies x^2-x=0$$ is equivalent to $$x+\sqrt{x}=0 \implies (x-\sqrt{x})(x+\sqrt{x})=0  \implies x^2-x=0$$

So it is the act of squaring which introduces a spurious solution associated with $x-\sqrt{x}=0$, and using imaginary numbers does not avoid this.

What does avoid squaring is the direct $$x+\sqrt{x}=0 \implies \sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}+1)=0$$ suggesting $\sqrt{x}=0$ or $\sqrt{x}=-1$, but now you need to consider the range and image of $\sqrt{x}$: if you believe $\sqrt{1}=1$ then there is no solution to $\sqrt{x}=-1$ so the only solution to the original equation is $x=0$.

Comment: What is happening here is what happens in learning. A consequence of information loss (which is what learning means in its nature) is false positives (collision in hash terminology). I saw this as an unnecessary information loss (goal is not abstraction here) but maybe may language is not adequate. So by eliminating that unnecessary step we would not ending seeking that information again by checking the solution.